# access last data added into json file

Tags: python, json

here I am creating a new customer and save it into a customers.json file

```
    new_user = appregister.newDocument('customers', username_1)
    new_user.set('username', username_1)
    new_user.set('email', email)
    new_user.save()

    new_user = format_customers()
    print(new_user)
    body_json = json.dumps(new_user)
    scriptuser = util.get_app_parameter("scriptuser", "beta")
    username = scriptuser["username"]
    password = scriptuser["password"]
    url = 'https://****.***.**/*****-****-1-0/****-****/customers.json'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    new_items = new_user
    body_json = json.dumps(new_items)

    status, headers, data = network.request(url, method='PUT',
                                            headers=headers,
                                            body=body_json,
                                            encoding='UTF-8',
                                               username=username,
                                               password=password)
```

here I want to send a mail to the customer(like when i register a new customer so the customer get an email with some random code) I don't think that I am accessing the customer email

```
    sources = ["customers.json"]
        for source in sources:
            data = util.get_data_item(source)
            if data is None or len(data) == 0:
                continue
            register = json.loads(data)
            for json_obj in register['customers']:
                try:
                    emailaddress = json_obj['email']

                    print(email) # I get NONE here 

                except Exception as e:
                    emailaddress = None
                if emailaddress:
                    if email == json_obj['email'].lower().strip():
                        code = "".join( [random.choice(string.digits) for i in xrange(6)] )
                        HTML = util.get_data_item("send_code2.html")
                        subject = (app_properties.get(EMAIL_TITLE_KEY))
                        try: 
                            messageText = 'Your code is : '+ code
                        except Exception, e:
                            response = {'status' : 'error', 'message' : str(e)}
                            return json.dumps(response), responseHeaders, 400
                        p = Properties()
                        p.load(StringReader(util.get_data_item('messages.properties')))
                        title = (p.getProperty('email.title', ''))
                        color = json.loads(util.get_data_item('theme.json'))['colors']['tint'][-6:]
                        imagedata = base64.b64encode(util.get_data_item_bytes('logo.png'))
                        messageHtml = Environment().from_string(HTML).render(code=code, title=title, color=color, imagedata=imagedata)
                        try:
                            sendEmail('no-reply@ggg.com', email, subject, messageHtml, messageText)
                        except Exception, e:
                            logger.error("ERROR " + str(e))
                            response = {'status' : 'error', 'message' : str(e)}
                            return json.dumps(response), responseHeaders, 400    
                        appRegister.put('activationcode', code);
                        appRegister.put('state', 'pending')
                        appRegister.put('activationtries', '0')
                        appRegister.put('email', email)
                        return json.dumps({}), responseHeaders, 200

        error = {'title': app_properties[REGISTRATION_ERROR_TITLE_KEY], 'message' : app_properties[REGISTRATION_ERROR_KEY]}


        return "200", responseHeaders
```

this is how my customers.json file looks like

```
{
    "customers": {
        "Osar": {
            "email": "gmail@gmail.com"
        },
        "eeforetzr": {
            "email": "email1@hotmail.com"
        },
        "aaxel": {
            "email": "hotmail@hotmail.com"
        }
        "Mark": {
            "email": "mark@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some explanation regarding your problem

Comment: When you print email, shouldn't it be emailaddress?